# When replying to an email in outlook 2010, how do I write in a specific color/font within the original message text?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook-2010

When replying to an email in outlook 2010, how do I write in a specific color/font within the original message text?

Alternately, in word, how do I say, write in X font/color regardless of the format in the surrounding text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazingly I have just figured this one out - I am so pleased cause it's bugged me forever too.

Click to reply to the mail in question then:

1. Click on the 'Options' ribbon tab.
2. Drop down the 'Colors' selection box.
3. Select 'Create a new Theme Colors...'
4. Change the 'Text/Background - Dark 1' and 'Text/Background - Dark 2' colours to your desired font colour.
5. Rename the style in the 'Name' box to reflect the colour you have chosen.
6. Click 'Save'

You can repeat this to create a number of colour themes for different circumstances, but now simply select your newly created colour theme and all text you have written in reply and any text you start writing from now will take on this colour without affecting other text on the email.  Perfect!

Comment: This is awesome.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in 2013 like this anymore.

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT:
>   Based on your comment, what you're asking for can't be done. It's a pretty basic feature of Microsoft Office products that text style information — font, color, size, &c. — is context-dependent.
>
> Original answer follows:

Perhaps I don't understand your question, but why don't you just select the text you want to modify and change the color with the normal color selection menus? Works fine for me when I insert sample text into original message text in a reply.

[image: color selection menus in Outlook]

Sorry for the semi-transparent window; I couldn't take a screenshot with it fully active.

Comment: oh.  good clarification.  i'd like to set it once and write in different part of the reply text with out having to go and change the color every time i move to a new area.  (what you describe is what i'm doing now...it's just tedious doing it over and over)